# Angular 4 Bundling - Complete Angular-Library included in bundle?

Tags: angular, bundle

I wonder if running **ng build --prod** in CMD, Angular takes all Javascript files from node_modules and creates the *vendor.bundle.js*?

Therefore I tried to remove some definitions in *package.json* and rebuild them. But it didn't change the file size.

Easy to reproduce in CMD (node-js installed):

> ng new testproject
>   cd testproject
>   ng build --prod

Now remember the file size in directory *dist*, remove some definitions in package.json and build again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng build --prod --aot`. The AOT (Ahead of Time Compilation) will tree shake your bundle, and it won't ship the compiler either.